# How can i set my WinUI3 program to be started in the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am currently developing a WinUI3 app, I want to my program starts in the center of the screen. How can i make this happen?

i tried

```
m_window = new MainWindow();
var hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(m_window);
Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);
Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
if (appWindow is not null)
{
    Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayArea displayArea = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(windowId, Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayAreaFallback.Nearest);
    if (displayArea is not null)
    {
        var CenteredPosition = appWindow.Position;
        CenteredPosition.X = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Width - appWindow.Size.Width) / 2);
        CenteredPosition.Y = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Height - appWindow.Size.Height) / 2);
        appWindow.Move(CenteredPosition);
    }
}
m_window.Activate();
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? Create a static `Center(Window window)` function with this code except the first and last line and a `window` parameter (instead of m_window), and do `this.Activated += (s, e) => Center(this);` in the constructor. Add a member variable so you run that Center only once (first time activated). This should work fine, or post a full reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Simon's comment I confirmed that this works:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using Windows.Graphics;
using WinRT.Interop;

namespace WinUISamples;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool centered;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (this.centered is false)
        {
            Center(this);
            centered = true;
        }
    }

    private static void Center(Window window)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
        WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);

        if (AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId) is AppWindow appWindow &&
            DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(windowId, DisplayAreaFallback.Nearest) is DisplayArea displayArea)
        {
            PointInt32 CenteredPosition = appWindow.Position;
            CenteredPosition.X = (displayArea.WorkArea.Width - appWindow.Size.Width) / 2;
            CenteredPosition.Y = (displayArea.WorkArea.Height - appWindow.Size.Height) / 2;
            appWindow.Move(CenteredPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

You also you can just use the [WinUIEx](https://github.com/dotMorten/WinUIEx) NuGet package.

```cs
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    window = new MainWindow();
    window.SetWindowSize(width: 700, height: 400);
    window.SetIsResizable(false);
    window.CenterOnScreen();
    window.Activate();
}
```

Comment: You should either add a boolean member variable like `bool _centered;` and set it in MainWindow_Activated or add a `this.Activated -= MainWindow_Activated;` line in MainWindow_Activated or you will center each time the app is activated.

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding in my program i have some code for blocking the user to resize the program but with these codes now they can resize it and i am using `appWindow.Resize(new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32 { Width = 700, Height = 400 });`
to resize my program and now it is not in the size that i gave to the app.  And also i am using some codes to remove the title bar and now there is a title bar in my app. How can i fix that?

Comment: Then I guess It'be easier just use WinUIEx. I updated my answer with a sample code. It's clean and simple.