# in .Net 6 Maui Blazor Hybrid App, How to make the window open in the center of the screen

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I'm creating a .Net Maui Blazor Hybrid app, and I want to open the window of the app at the center of the screen. if someone know how to do, can you please drop a comment (reply). Thank You.

i did try searching several posts about the issue but didn't find any satisfying result. and i have attach the app class code bellow.

```
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;
#endif

namespace ApplicationName;

public partial class App : Application
{
    const int WindowWidth = 1360;
    const int WindowHeight = 700;

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var mauiWindow = handler.VirtualView;
            var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
            nativeWindow.Activate();
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
            WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
            AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
            appWindow.Resize(new SizeInt32(WindowWidth, WindowHeight));
#endif
        });

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of article about this, all for WinUI, [Open app always in the center of the display - Windows 11 (WinUi 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71730765/10528003), [How can i set my WinUI3 program to be started in the center of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74890915/10528003)

Let me give you the same solution but without the Interop calls.

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Platform;
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;
#endif

public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();

        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var windowWidth = 1360;
            var windowHeight = 700;
            var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
            var appWindow = nativeWindow.GetAppWindow();

            if (appWindow is not null)
            {
                appWindow.Resize(new SizeInt32(windowWidth, windowHeight));

                var windowId = appWindow.Id;
                DisplayArea displayArea = DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(windowId, DisplayAreaFallback.Nearest);
                if (displayArea is not null)
                {
                    PointInt32 CenteredPosition = new()
                    {
                        X = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Width - appWindow.Size.Width) / 2),
                        Y = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Height - appWindow.Size.Height) / 2)
                    };
                    appWindow.Move(CenteredPosition);
                }
            }
            nativeWindow.Activate();
#endif
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the center position of the screen and then move the window. Such as:

```
     public App()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         MainPage = new AppShell();
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var mauiWindow = handler.VirtualView;
            var nativeWindow = handler.PlatformView;
            nativeWindow.Activate();
            IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(nativeWindow);
            Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
            Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
            if (appWindow is not null)
            {
                Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayArea displayArea = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayArea.GetFromWindowId(windowId, Microsoft.UI.Windowing.DisplayAreaFallback.Nearest);
                if (displayArea is not null)
                {
                    var CenteredPosition = appWindow.Position;
                    CenteredPosition.X = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Width - appWindow.Size.Width) / 2);
                    CenteredPosition.Y = ((displayArea.WorkArea.Height - appWindow.Size.Height) / 2);
                    appWindow.Move(CenteredPosition);
                }
            }
#endif
        });
    }
```